# RmShutdown Explorer.exe with GetShellWindow hangs for 30 seconds

Tags: windows, winapi

Restarting the shell is required when registering shell extensions like context menues and icon overlays. What our installer used to do is the old and simple "Find the process handle by name then TerminateProcess", and I'm trying to switch to using the `Restart Manager API` which [allegedly](https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/windows-restart-manager-part-1/) specializes handling `Explorer.exe`. Great, and it works, by using `GetShellWindow` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to retrieve the pid and passing it to `RmRegisterResources`. The only problem is that sometimes the `RmShutdown` call takes 30 seconds to return, as indicated by the progress callback (always stuck at 81% for 30s)(It seems to be related to the amount of explorer windows opened). Now I really don't want to use the old "TerminateProcess" method since an officially supported method exists, but I currently have no leg to stand on due to this 30 second hang; a 30 second blackout during installation really isn't quite user friendly. Anyone knows why `RmShutdown` hangs for 30 seconds when restarting the shell?

P.S. I'm also passing the `RmForceShutdown` flag  to `RmShutdown`, and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/nf-restartmanager-rmshutdown), the api waits for a certain timeout and if the program hasn't exit it would be force killed. It seems like the 30 seconds were because `Explorer.exe` didn't respond to `RmShutdown`? But why?

Edit: I tried running `RmShutdown` without `RmForceShutdown`, and it failed with `ERROR_FAIL_SHUTDOWN`; the [AppStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/ns-restartmanager-rm_process_info) returned by `RmGetList` reads 0x11, which means `RmStatusRunning` and `RmStatusErrorOnStop`.

Comment: Instead of using GetShellWindow you can gather all "explorer.exe" processes ran from %windir% directory as there can be multiple explorer processes running. Now, FWIW, that being said I observe sometimes the same behavior and I sometimes have to kill these (but I try the nicest way first). For wait time, I use what's configured there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc976045(v=technet.10). Why is so? because Explorer may have many 3rd parties dll injected into it that may prevent it from shutting down nicely...